# How to redirect with parameters in routing.yml?

Tags: symfony

In the routing.yml you can do things like:

```
redirect_old_url_to_new:
    pattern:   /old-pattern
    defaults:  
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /new-pattern
        permanent: true
```

Which will redirect the url `/old-pattern` to `/new-pattern`. However, if I have a parameter, how can the parameter be translated in the new path, e.g.:

```
redirect_old_url_to_new:
    pattern:   /old-pattern/{page}
    defaults:  
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /new-pattern/{page}
        permanent: true
```

This is NOT working and will redirect to `/new-pattern/{page}` literally and will therefore redirect from `/old-pattern/23` to  `/new-pattern/{page}`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the parameter name is identical, then the parameter will be passed automatically:

```
FirstRoute:
  pattern: /firstroute/{page}
  defaults:
      _controller: Bundle:Controller:action

# SecondRoute will redirect to FirstRoute. 
# ex: /secondroute/1 redirects to /firstroute/1            
SecondRoute:
  pattern: /secondroute/{page}
  defaults:
      _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
      route: FirstRoute
      permanent: true
```

Comment: if the destination route has less parameters than the route being redirected would it still work?

Comment: It will work but extra parameters end up as query parameters to the url.

Comment: @DavidLin: In Symfony 2.8 (maybe previous versions too), you can ignore extra parameters by setting the `ignoreAttributes` key in `defaults`. For instance, `ignoreAttributes: [name, age]` will ignore the extra `name` and `age` parameters, so they will not appear in the URL.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like there is a mistake in Symfony's Book

```
root:
    pattern: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /app
        permanent: true
```

As Arms said, it's "FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect" and not "FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect"

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong earlier, this works for me :

```
redirection:
    path: /exercices.html
    defaults:
      _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
      route: blog
      slug: url-of-the-post
      permanent: true
```

Put directly `parameter_name: parameter_value` under `route`.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the root in .yml like this:

```
root:
    path: redirected_path
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: destination_path
        permanent: true|false
```

or

```
root:
    path: redirected_path
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: destination_route_name
        permanent: true|false
```